# Building a fat jar in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, build

I am trying to build a fat jar in netbeans. When I hit clean, it shows me the following error:

> C:\workspace\Travel_Agency\nbproject\build-impl.xml:63: Source
>   resource does not exist:
>   C:\workspace\Travel_Agency\dist\nblibraries.properties

And clicking on the error, it sends me to the following line in the build-impl.xml file:

```
<loadproperties encoding="ISO-8859-1" srcfile="${libraries.path}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Does that file exist? `C:\workspace\Travel_Agency\dist\nblibraries.properties`
If not, where did you put that file? You may have to change libraries.path so that it points to that actual location. If the file does exist, but you are still getting that error, then make sure you have the necessary permissions to access it.